# Where can I find com.ibm.websphere.runtime.CustomService Configuration details of existing services?

Tags: websphere, websphere-8

I am working on WebSphere migration. I have an application which is deployed on the WebSphere application server

as it Seems. The application needs some of the class files.

These classes are loaded using  `com.ibm.websphere.runtime.CustomService`

As I do not have access to the WebSphere Admin Console. is there any configuration file in which CustomService config settings are stored?

Answer (score 0):

I tried creating one as documented here https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7JFU_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.express.iseries.doc/ae/trun_customservice.html and the configuration seems to be stored in server.xml of the server where the custom service is defined.